# Liferay 6.2 How to display images stored in Documents and Media

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I would like to know all possible ways of displaying a DLFileEntry image in a jsp of a custom portlet.
More specifically, I currently use the following way but I have some issues with DLFileEntry objects that have zero values for 'largeimageid'

```java
DLFileEntry image = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(long_id);
String imageUrl = themeDisplay.getPathImage() + "/image_gallery?img_id=" + image.getLargeImageId() +  "&t=" + WebServerServletTokenUtil.getToken(image.getLargeImageId());
```

Which are the alternatives of getting the image url without use of the large image id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is the pattern similar to the one that is used by Liferay ***Documents and Media*** portlet:

```java
DLFileEntry image = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntry(long_id);
String imageUrl = "";
if (image != null) {
    imageUrl =
        PortalUtil.getPortalURL(request) + "/documents/" + image.getGroupId() + "/" +
            image.getFolderId() + "/" + image.getTitle() + "/" + image.getUuid() + "?t=" +
            System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Where `PortalUtil.getPortalURL(request)` will return you base URL of your portal based on `httpServletRequest`, `System.currentTimeMillis()` will give you current time (miliseconds), and rest of the parameters are all available through `DLFileEntry` object.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611033/liferay-dynamic-data-lists-how-to-get-image-url

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

```
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFolder" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFolderLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portlet.imagegallery.service.IGImageLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portlet.imagegallery.model.IGImage" %>

<%@ include file="init.jsp" %>

<%
    String igFolderId = portletPreferences.getValue("igFolderId", "0");
    String cycleSpeed = portletPreferences.getValue("cycleSpeed", "1000");
    String fxSpeed = portletPreferences.getValue("fxSpeed", "1000");
    String type = portletPreferences.getValue("type", "fade");
    String height = portletPreferences.getValue("height", "480");
    String width = portletPreferences.getValue("width", "640");

    List<IGImage> images = IGImageLocalServiceUtil.getImages(Long.valueOf(igFolderId));
%>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= Long.valueOf(igFolderId) != 0%>">
        <div id="<portlet:namespace />images">
            <%
                for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)  {
                    IGImage image = images.get(i);
            %>
                <img width="<%= width %>" height="<%= height %>" src="/image/image_gallery?img_id=<%=image.getLargeImageId()%>" alt="<%=image.getDescription()%>" <%= i == 0 ? "" : "style=\"display:none;\""%>/>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </div>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <span class="portlet-msg-info">
            Please configure this portlet.
        </span>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(
        function() {
            jQuery("#<portlet:namespace />images").cycle({
                fx:    '<%= type %>',
                speed:  <%= fxSpeed %>,
                timeout: <%= cycleSpeed %>
             });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Greetings!

Comment: What you posted contains the large image id: img_id=<%=image.getLargeImageId()%> which is the one I want to avoid when displaying an image. Check again my question.