# Liferay Dynamic Data Lists: How to get image URL?

Tags: dynamic, liferay, velocity, datalist

I am creating a custom template in velocity for a Dynamic Data Lists and I want to get the image URL for the selected image. How can I get it?

The code is:

```
#set ( $DDLRecordService =  $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService") )
#set ( $records = $DDLRecordService.getRecords($mathTool.toNumber($reserved_record_set_id)) )

#foreach ($record in $records)
    #set( $fields = $record.getFields() )
    #set( $URL = $fields.get("URL").getValue() )
    #set( $Link = $fields.get("Linktitle").getValue() )
    #set( $Preview = $fields.get("Vorschaubild").getValue() ) ##the image is here

    $URL
    $Link
    $Preview
#end
```

The `$preview` output is:  `{"groupId":"0000000","uuid":"ccdaccec-00a0-4284-a000-589be48‌​99281","version":"1.‌​0"}`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does `$fields.get("Vorschaubild").getValue()` is returning image's URL?

Comment: no, it return the object's attributes I guess: {"groupId":"0000000","uuid":"ccdaccec-00a0-4284-a000-589be4899281","version":"1.0"}

Comment: Is there `imageId` in it?

Comment: no, I posted all the output: groupId,uuid,version

Comment: Your question is not clear, where are you setting that imagE?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: What is `$records`? Where are you filling it?

Comment: $records are the elements of a list, if I am tring to make a dynamic datalist template. Elemets composed by a description, a url and an image... I thought was clear enough...

Answer (score 0):

Itt will work if you replace UUID_HERE to the real UUID.

```
<a href='${themeDisplay.getPortalURL()}/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=UUID_HERE&groupId=${themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()}'>MyFile OR Image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came across similar situation and after searching on the internet for hour(s), didn't find any useful information apart from [**LPS-34792**](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-34792) ticket.

Well, you can render image on the UI from a Documents and Media field using:

```
<#assign hasPicture = cur_record.getFieldValue("picture")?has_content>

<#if hasPicture>
    <#assign picture = jsonFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(cur_record.getFieldValue("picture"))>
    <img src='/documents/${picture.getString("groupId")}/${picture.getString("uuid")}' />
</#if>
```

Where `picture` is the name of field and `hasPicture` will check if the image was selected.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863921/liferay-6-2-how-to-display-images-stored-in-documents-and-media